# Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T'

Tags: typescript

I am a seasoned javascript developer that recently learned C# as my first statically typed language. My next project is using typescript so I've been brushing up on it.

This is my code:

```
interface IMonad<T> {
    get(): T;
    set<T>(fn: (value: T) => T): IMonad<T>;
}

class LazyMonad<T> implements IMonad<T>
{
    private value: T;
    private binds;

    constructor(value: T)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.binds = [];
    }

    get(): T
    {
        return this.binds
            .reduce(function (v: T, fn): T {
                return (v === null) ? null : v + fn(v);
            }, this.value);
    }

    set<T>(fn: (value: T) => T): LazyMonad<T>
    {
        this.binds.push(fn);
        return this;
    }
}
```

---

Edit: I also have this class that implements `IMonad<T>`

```
class IdentityMonad<T> implements IMonad<T>
{
    private value: T;

    constructor(value: T)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    get(): T
    {
        return this.value;
    }

    set<T>(fn: (value: T) => T): IdentityMonad<T>
    {
        return new IdentityMonad<T>(fn(this.value));
    }
}
```

---

Here is the error I'm getting from `tsc`:

> src/lazy_monad.ts(25,10): error TS2322: Type 'this' is not assignable
>   to type 'LazyMonad'.   Type 'LazyMonad' is not assignable to
>   type 'LazyMonad'.
>       Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T'.

My implementation might be wrong here but I believe this would work in C#. Advice?

Comment: Did you mean to make `set<T>` generic? I think you might want it to use the `T` from the class rather than the `T` from the method for something that's a get/set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you might want to make `set` use `T` from the class rather than it having its own generic constraint. Removing that will fix your error.

From there you might want to consider using a polymorphic this:

```
interface IMonad<T> {
    get(): T;
    set(fn: (value: T) => T): this; // use this as the return type
}

class LazyMonad<T> implements IMonad<T>
{
    private value: T;
    private binds: ((value: T) => T)[]; // you might want to add this type here too

    constructor(value: T)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.binds = [];
    }

    get()
    {
        return this.binds
            .reduce(function (v: T, fn): T {
                return (v === null) ? null : v + fn(v);
            }, this.value);
    }

    set(fn: (value: T) => T)
    {
        this.binds.push(fn);
        return this;
    }
}

// lazyMonad would be typed as LazyMonad<number> here
var lazyMonad = new LazyMonad(5).set((val) => val);
```

This will also work with `IdentityMonad`.

See the section [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/release-notes/typescript-1.7.html) on "this-typing" for more detail on how this works.

Comment: I have another class IdentityMonad<T> that implements IMonad<T> but set<T>() does return a new IdentityMonad<T> each time its called. Is this breaking the contract with the interface I currently have? I'm still learning the typing paradigm.

Comment: @Kylee I just realized `set<T>` is generic.

Comment: Removing the generic constraint from set worked and that makes sense why it wasn't working. Thanks!